# How to assign permissions to logined user to show or edit their own Profile with SonataAdminBundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Symfony2.8.10 + SonataAdminbundle + FosUserBundle/SonataUserBundle

The user can edit all users when i try to assign sonata user permission to a user. But if i don't do this, the logined user can not show their profile.what should I do?

[My acl setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka4AQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting acl for an action not depending on the variable passed to it. Still you can check that if a person is logged in and have the user editing level, this person can edit only his profile. If the person is an administrator then he can edit all profiles.

I do not think sonata admin is really done for that as fos_user implements already its own logic for that. You can find the form under the url : `/{fos_user_route}/profile/edit/`. I prefer to use back-office for administrators and front-office for the rest. Moreover, it help the overall security as the user do not know the link to the back-office.